# Стиль первого элемента массива

Tags: php, css

Нужно отдельно задать стиль для первого элемента из массива, массив задается дивами и элементы идентичны друг другу. Можете подсказать, как такое выполнить?

Comment: НЕ понял я что-то чего ты добиться хочешь?

Comment: Подряд идут 14 div элементов, http://h1964807.stratoserver.net/files/share/26_12_2011/irH0HyW73kVtnA1akZnyw.png. Нужно через css отдельно задать стиль для первого элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/6wmcf/12/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = 1;
foreach ($array as $text) {
  echo '<div'
  if ($first) { echo ' style="color:red"'} else $first--;
  echo '>'.$text.'</div>';
}
```

Или:

```
echo '<div style="color:red">'.$array[0].'</div>';
for ($i = 1, $c = count($array); $i < $c; $i++)
  echo '<div>'.$array[$i].'</div>';
```

Это то, что понятно из вопроса.